# phone on bootloop with a problem in the cache

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-5, boot-loop, bootloader

My phone somehow got stuck in a boot loop and I can't fix it. I don't know what to do. I cant get pass the start up animation no matter what I do.

I've tried the fast boot commands to flash  and keep getting the error (i dont really know alot about flashing and never done it before but the that what i found suggested in the web..)

FAILED < remote: flash write failure >
I've tried the flash-all.bat file, but the lock state goes back to LOCKED when it reboots the device and I get the error

not supported on lock device
I can unlock the device when I type fastboot oem unlock, but if the device is restarted it goes back to LOCKED.

I've tried recovery mode and I see the below statements:

E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_install
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
I've tried wipe data/factory reset

--Wiping data...
Formatting /data...
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
Formatting /cache...
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_install
Data wipe complete
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_log
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_log
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)
E:Can't mount /ache/recovery/last_install
E:Can't open /ache/recovery/last_install
E:failed to mount /cache (Invalid argument)

Comment: You need to enter the recovery mode and clear the cache. What is the "flash-all.bat" that you are talking about? I take it you attempted to flash a new ROM and then the bootloop happened? What ROM?

Comment: the original rom from google ....  and the bootloop happend before....

Comment: @RyanConrad. flash-all.bat is a script included in the Google factory images for flashing.

Comment: Have you tried [WugFresh Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)? It's really simple to use.